# How to html+javascrip code convert to react-hook

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

**this is code html + javascipt show map of Longdomap and i want to convert to React Hook**

this is doucument Longdomap [enter link description here](https://map.longdo.com/docs/javascript/getting-started)

*Thanks in advance for the answer*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Create Map Sample | Longdo Map</title>
        <style type="text/css">
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.longdo.com/map/?key=[YOUR-KEY-API]"></script>
        <script>
          function init() {
            var map = new longdo.Map({
              placeholder: document.getElementById('map')
            });
          }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
      <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:
First, add the following script tag to the index.html in the public folder replacing the [YOUR-KEY-API] with actual key :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.longdo.com/map/?key=[YOUR-KEY-API]"></script>
```

Create a React function component like below:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const MyMap = () => {

    const init = () => {
         var map = new longdo.Map({
            placeholder: document.getElementById('map')
         });
   }

    useEffect(() => {
         init();
    }, []);

    return (<div id="map"></div>);

}

export default MyMap;
```

import and create the compoenent this where you need to show it:

```
    ...
    <MyMap/>
    ...
```

Comment: @Somkiat Chathanoi, check this out!